# auto incrementing version number in yml file

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, yaml

I am working with a Gitlab Pipeline. The file being used for the pipeline is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. I am using the `Semantic Versioning` method in order to obtian the version numbers for changes in the code in the form of ( breaking, feat fix ) which translats to ( major.minor.patch ). "breaking", "feat" and "fix would be specified as part of a commit message. So, it would be someting like:

```
vi testme.txt
git add .
git commit -m "fix : changed the file "
```

If the Version ( in the .txt file on Amazon ) is on 0.0.1, it would then - with the code below- the version would be increased to 0.0.2

The code was initially written using bash but then changed so that it would work in the yaml (`.gitlab-ci.yml`) file. When generating the version using bash, I would get 0.0.2. When generating the version in the yml file, I get ..2

There seems to be something wrong with the string conversion but I am not sure

```
# Convert major, minor, and patch to strings before concatenating
CURR_VERSION_NO="${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
```

How can I change this so that I can get an answer of 0.0.2 in the yml code

Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

```
  job_2:
    stage: get_version_no
    tags:
      - simba
      - bash
      - small
    script:
      - FVER="0.0.0"
      - |
        if aws s3 ls "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/gitlab_repo/ver_${REPOSITORY_NAME}.txt" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
          FVER=$(aws s3 cp "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/gitlab_repo/ver_${REPOSITORY_NAME}.txt" - | tr -d '\r\n')
        fi

        PREV_VERSION_NO=$FVER

        COMMIT_MSG=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 | tr -d '\n')

        case "$COMMIT_MSG" in
          *breaking*) RELEASE_LEVEL="major" ;;
          *feat*) RELEASE_LEVEL="minor" ;;
          *fix*) RELEASE_LEVEL="patch" ;;
          *)
            echo "Commit message must contain 'breaking', 'feat', or 'fix'"
            exit 1
            ;;
        esac

        case "$RELEASE_LEVEL" in
            major)
                major=$(( $(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $1}') + 1 ))
                minor=0
                patch=0
                echo " major $major / minor $minor / patch $patch"
                ;;
            minor)
                major=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $1}')
                minor=$(( $(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $2}') + 1 ))
                patch=0
                echo " major $major / minor $minor / patch $patch"
                ;;
            patch)
                major=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $1}')
                minor=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $2}')
                patch=$(( $(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F. '{print $3}') + 1 ))
                echo " major $major / minor $minor / patch $patch"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Invalid RELEASE_LEVEL"
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac


        CURR_VERSION_NO="$major.$minor.$patch"
        echo "New CURR_VERSION_NO: $CURR_VERSION_NO"

        # Convert major, minor, and patch to strings before concatenating
        CURR_VERSION_NO="${major}.${minor}.${patch}"

        echo "$CURR_VERSION_NO" | aws s3 cp - "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/gitlab_repo/ver_${REPOSITORY_NAME}.txt"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Execution of aws s3 cp successful CURR_VERSION_NO => $CURR_VERSION_NO ."
        else
          echo "Execution of aws s3 cp FAILED CURR_VERSION_NO => $CURR_VERSION_NO ."
          exit 1
        fi
```

Comment: Nowhere have you defined `CI_COMMIT_TAG`.

Comment: FYI, there is a [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) tool that you can use to fully automate the semantic versioning process.

Comment: Why do you have two identical assignments to `CURR_VERSION_NO`? BTW, wouldn't it be better (and easier to maintain), if you don't put such complex code into the git yml file, but instead into a script, and just call the script from the yml file? You have then much better debugging capabilities.

Comment: I'm confused what this is, it's half yaml, half bash script. Have you considered using yaml-tools to edit your yaml files programatically?

Comment: @xpusostomos - initially, it was partially bash script and partially yml - now it is all yml

Comment: @blhsing - I was using Gitlab and the CI variables are part of the gitlab structure. But, I saw that this was not the correct one to use

Comment: @user1934428 - I saw that i had made some mistakes beffore posting. I am using Gitlab. What seemed to be happening is that when the gitlab-runner was doing its builds, it seemed to be referring to old versions of the bash script (at least according to the error logs). Not sure what was going on there - so - I just moved everything to yml.

Comment: Thanks all - fixed the code and all is working correctly. Will go ahead and close the message  Thanks!

Comment: Hi,

What was the final solution? (is the code shown working? I don't see edited so I'm assuming it is the original non-working code)